# how to make a custom height video container and making contents display on top of that container

Tags: html, video, background, html5-video

I want to make a custom height video background for a specific div container and display contents like headings,paragraphs on top of it...
When I keep the height at 100%, the video works just fine with full width..But when I try to resize the height, the width also reduces.

How do I make the video display at a height of 500px for example and keep the width at full width...and to display a small paragraph with a heading in center of the video.

```css
video#videobg {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <video autoplay poster="Cheer-Up.jpg" id="videobg" loop>
    <div><p>Something here</p></div>
    <source src="Cheer-Up.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="Cheer-Up.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using CSS to set a specific height for the video container, but also setting the width you want it to stay. put this in your header.

```
<style>
    #videobg {
        height: <PUT YOUR HEIGHT HERE>;
        width: <PUT YOUR WIDTH HERE>;
    }
</style>
```

also, put the width at a specific pixel count. the 100% could change depending on the height.

Comment: setting a custom width doesn't work and if it works i don't think it look nice when I reduce the size of the window, some part of video gets cut of to other side...maybe in different screen sizes....

Comment: looking at the w3 schools page (a good resource starting out web design), forgo the CSS and change the html video tag to include a width attribute, like this: <video autoplay poster="Cheer-Up.jpg" id="videobg" width="320" height="240" loop> specify your measurements in pixels.

Comment: No, my friend..It isn't working.The video  only keeps resizing I try to change the width or height..For ex. if i make width to 1800px and make height 300 px..the whole video change to width of 600px...I mean one depends on another... How about changing the positions and display properties...Thanks for the help again.

Comment: i found an answer in this page.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009317/containing-a-video-background-to-a-specific-div?rq=1